# WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to set up Selenium but can't get the code in Eclipse to invoke Browser. I have the following code:

```
package Basics;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Browserinvocation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

    }

}
```

I receive the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type
    ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type

    at Basics.Browserinvocation.main(Browserinvocation.java:11)
```

There was a similar question on StackOverflow, the solution was that there were 2 Jars outside the "Lib" folder that wasn't added. I was missing those as well, but even after adding those Jars, I'm still receiving the same error

Also, when I hover over "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;", I get the following message:

```
The import org.openqa cannot be resolved
```

Comment: Sounds like you still have jar problems. Find a tutorial and follow their setup guide and make sure you have all the newest drivers, etc. and they match your browser version.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it adding to my java project libraries the external jar `client-combined-3.2.0-nodeps.jar`, wich hasn't been added previously because it was in the root folder.